# Как выполнить метод с findViewById из другого класса

Tags: java, android

В class'e **MainActivity()**, у меня есть метод `MyMethod()` в котором содержится:

```
CombinedChart chart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
```

В class'e **SecActivity()**, я вызываю этот метод таким образом:

```
MainActivity MaiAct= new MainActivity();
                      MaiAct.MyMethod();
```

В итоге получаю ошибку:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Вроде понятно, что `findViewById` ищет `R.id.chart`, которого нет. Предполагаю что проблема с `View`, но перепробовал несколько способов и что-то ни один не подходит.

Подскажите, как решить проблему?

Comment: У каждой `Activity` есть своя разметка. Поэтому и не находит. Проще передать `SecActivity`'у аргумент (параметр) `chart`

Comment: вы не можете обращаться к виджетам активити, которой нет в данный момент на экране, потому что в этот момент нет ни этих виджетов, ни активити, в которой они находятся. Активити - системный компонент и простое создание ее экземпляра никаким образом не создает тот компонент, который можно назвать активити. Опишите свою задачу более подробно, что именно вы хотите сделать в итоге, а не ваш неправильный способ ее решения.